# Why does clearFindViewByIdCache() have to be called in onDestroyView()?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm trying to understand Kotlin Android extensions and [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-android-extensions-the-definitive-guide-786d190b30e7) says says:

```
When asked for a view, it will try to find it in the cache. If it’s not there, it will find it and add it to the cache. Pretty simple indeed.

Besides, it adds a function to clear the cache: clearFindViewByIdCache. You can use it for instance if you have to rebuild the view, as the old views won't be valid anymore.
```

Why won't the old views be valid anymore once you rebuild the view after onDestroy()? The view references are still going to be there once you rebuild the view, for example in OnActivityCreated().

Answer (score 0):

The important note here is that Fragments usually have a longer lifecycle then their views. Let's consider the following flow:

1. You created `Fragment A` and placed it into a container
2. `Fragment A` view got created (this onCreateView + onViewCreated)
3. You created `Fragment B` and replace `Fragment A` with the new fragment in the container + keep back stack
4. `Fragment A` views will be destroyed at this moment, but the fragment will be kept inside of `FragmentManager`.
5. You `back press` and Fragment B got fully destroyed because you logically leaving that. At this moment system replaces it back with `Fragment A` and it creates a new view again.

**So here are a few important notes:**

At step #4 if you keep any links to subviews, then your memory just leaks because all of them already got detached out of your view hierarchy and can't be used anymore. Basically, you still hold all those views in memory, even though they are not in use anymore. Usually, ppl don't notice that and all views will get rebound again with new onViewCreated (and `findViewById`), but kotlin extensions keep them in a cache and basically do not execute this `findViewById` again, so you can get old (read as dead) views that are not those views that just got created.

If you use ButterKnife at the moment for instance, they have description about that as well in `Binding Reset` section. (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/#reset).

Last important note is that Kotlin extensions do this job for you, so you don't really need to call it inside of onDestroyView, you just use it and it works (as magic...)

Comment: "You back press and Fragment B got fully destroyed because you logically leaving that." I thought only the view would get destroyed?

Comment: "all of them already got detached out of your view hierarchy and can't be used anymore" Can't they be used once the fragment view is rebuilt? (e.g. onActivityCreated())?

Comment: >> I thought only the view would get destroyed?
A: not in the case when you go back in terms of back stack. You logically leaving your fragment, so your Fragment B will be destroyed fully.

>> Can't they be used once the fragment view is rebuilt?
A: no, the fragment will create a new view (usually inflate from XML). So if you keep a reference to old views, you basically hold the memory from being freed up.

>> (e.g. onActivityCreated())
A: Activity usually has even longer lifecycle then fragments. Fragment's view can be created/destroyed while Activity basically stays in the same state.